# What are non-latest Eclipse Oomph repository addresses?

Tags: eclipse, downgrade

Latest Eclipse is experiencing this critical issue with GTK: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=568859

And I want to downgrade it. But the Oomph repository contains only the latest address and will not allow me to downgrade through the **Help > About > Installation Details > Installations History > Revert**.

Where can I find Oomph `1.18.0.v20200701` for example? Maybe even some earlier version, `1.17` will definitely work.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.oomph.jreinfo,1.14.0.v20200624-1156
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.oomph.jreinfo.ui,1.12.0.v20200624-1156
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.oomph.p2.core,1.17.0.v20200624-1156
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.oomph.p2,1.17.0.v20200701-0751
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.oomph.p2.ui,1.14.0.v20200701-0751
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.oomph.setup,1.18.0.v20200624-1156
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core,1.18.0.v20200624-1156
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.oomph.setup.editor,1.18.0.v20200624-1156
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.oomph.setup,1.18.0.v20200701-0751
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2,1.16.0.v20200624-1156
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui,1.18.0.v20200701-0701
```

(ignore the fonts, it's GTK/KDE issue on Wayland)
[image: repositories screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update site ***Oomph Latest Milestone*** points to the latest milestone or release which was the first milestone of Oomph 1.18 (**1.18.0-M1**) **at the time you did the installation** to which you now want **to revert**. But now it points to the Oomph 1.19 release. So everything of Oomph 1.18.0-M1 cannot be found anymore.

**Adding** the following **update site** should allow reverting to the installation you want to:

[`https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/drops/milestone/S20200715-042823-1.18.0-M1/`](https://download.eclipse.org/oomph/drops/milestone/S20200715-042823-1.18.0-M1/)